# Insert data into mysql with sprintf and R using text input boxes

Tags: mysql, r

I have a Shiny Dashboard app and i want to dynamically add messages, tasks and notifications into MySQL datatable called "messagesTable" through the use of three textInput boxes named "from" "message" and "time".

I have created three textInput boxes in the shinydashboard app with the names "from", "message" and "time".  Through an oberveEvent coding and an action button, i want to add the message details to mysql table "messagesTable"

My sql code is as follows:

```
# Insert message
  observeEvent(input$newMsg,{
      req(input$from, input$message, input$time)

    result <- sprintf("INSERT INTO messagesTable (from, message, time) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')",
                        input$from, input$message, input$time)
    #check sql construction
    print(result)
    #send to database
    dbSendQuery(con, result)

    })
```

I get an error message:

> Warning: Error in .local: could not run statement: You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, message, time)
>   VALUES ('bbbb', 'bbbb', 'bbbbb')' at line 1
>
> <sup>Created on 2019-08-05 by the [reprex
>   package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Maybe you missed the last "closing" `;`

Comment: from and time are reserved words in mysql. try enclosing them in backticks

Comment: Many thanks, adding a "closing" ; and using backticks solves the problem